# How to check whether an infinite set is closed under addition with a computer code?

Tags: c++, math, matlab, wolfram-mathematica, set

Given *k* positive integer numbers a<sub>1</sub> < a<sub>2</sub> < a<sub>3</sub> < ... < a<sub>k</sub>, and all integers greater than a<sub>k</sub>, we want to check whether the set A = {a<sub>i</sub> : i ∈ [1,k]} ∪ {n : n > a<sub>k</sub>, n ∈ ℕ } = {a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ... , a<sub>k</sub>, a<sub>k</sub>+1, a<sub>k</sub>+2, ...} is closed under addition. This means that:

∑<sub>1 ≤ i ≤ k</sub> a<sub>i</sub>*b<sub>i</sub> ∈ A, for any non-negative integers b<sub>i</sub>.

For example, {2,4,6,7,8,....} is closed under addition.

Is there any easy way to do this? Any functions that we could use in Mathematica or Matlab?

Comment: If the set is infinite, how do you know what all of its members are?

Comment: As you can see in the set A above, after the element `a_k`, we have `a_k+1,a_k+2,a_k+3` and so on. Each is increased by one from their left number.

Comment: @OsirisXu: SO supports ordered and unordered lists by prefixing each item with "1. " for ordered or "* ", "- " or "+ " for unordered. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the discontinuous portion less than *k* of the sets are not large I believe you can approach it directly like this:

```
a = {2, 4, 6};
Tr /@ Subsets[a, {2}];
TakeWhile[%, # < Last@a &];
Complement[%, a] === {}
```

Comment: @Osiris You're welcome, and thanks for the accept.  Is this fast enough for your purposes, or do you need something better optimized?

Comment: "If the sets are not large"?  Not sure you can get much larger than an "infinite set" (ok, there are sparse infinite sets and dense infinite sets, but both are large).  And any finite subset you take will definitely NOT be closed, so this doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: @Ben, perhaps I am misunderstanding the problem, or failing to reason, but I mean the finite portion of the set less than `a_k`.

Comment: So what you meant was, "if `k` is not large"?

Comment: I just realized that there should be a further story here. To check whether the set is complete, we should also check whether the addition of `a_i` with itself with multiple times is also included in the set.

Comment: @Ben I see your point.  I'll change the wording as you suggest.

Comment: @OsirisXu: Using the induction hypothesis that the sum of any two members of the set is in the set and the commutative property of addition, it follows that the sum of any number of members is also in the set.

Comment: @Ben I was just reviewing the updated question; is it your understanding that my post still answers the question in its present state?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, induction guarantees the case of non-negative integer weights.  Wait, no it doesn't, there's one corner case not covered...

Answer (score 2):

A banal observation: any sum having an operand `>= a_k` is a member of A, so you only need to be concerned with sums where both operands are from the set `B = {a_1 .. a_(k-1)}`. Naive solution in pseudocode:

```
for i from k-1 down to 1
  for j from i down to 1
    if (a_i + a_j < a_k) and (a_i + a_j is not in B) then
      return false
return true
```

Comment: Thanks, LaC. But the question is how to quickly check whether `a_i + a_j` is not in B. Another loop?

Comment: Use binary search, assuming B is sorted.

Comment: `a_k` is "a positive number".  The question doesn't guarantee it's an integer.  So I think you need to include `a_k` in the set `B`, and when `a_i + a_j > a_k` you need to test whether the sum is an integer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: since he expressed "all integers greater than a_k" as `a_k+1, a_k+2 ...`, that would have made a_k integer as well, and I assumed that he simply forgot to specify that a_1 ... a_k were integers.

Answer (score 0):

Your recent modification to the question makes it ridiculous.  I note that:

- `a_1` through `a_k` are all strictly positive integers
- the remaining members of the set are strictly greater than `a_k`, hence also strictly positive integers

Therefore, all members of the set are **strictly positive integers**.

But `∑a_i*n_i ∈ A` clearly does not hold for all non-negative integers `n_i`.

Specifically, it does not hold for `n_i = 0`, because the sum is zero, and zero is not a strictly positive integer, hence not a member of the set.

Now, that's an extremely weird definition of "closed set", and not the commonly accepted usage.  But by your definition, the set is NOT closed, for any `k > 0`.

Comment: I agree, the new definition OP gives for "closed under addition" is bogus. It looks like he's going for "closed under linear combination" now.